# Is separating common data is good in my case?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, database-design

So, for example, I have City column. 95% of City values are NULL. Is this good idea to make table like city_names(Id PK, City) and replace City with new column City_id (FK references city_names(id))? Here is my thoughts on this. They are based on general ideas of computation. Correct me please it this not apply for RDMS.

First way: O(n) storage O(n) bulk operations O(1) random access

Second way: O(n) storage O(n * logn) bulk operations due to n requests to index structure (B-trees, for ex) O(lon n) random access

**Here is full picture**. I have 1M row table. It grows. There is 80 columns like City. They all almost NULL'ed. However, they are community-editable. So I must provide fulltext search, fast editing times and complex queries (for advanced users or bots) among them. In some future there will be no NULLs at all. So winch scheme I must use for editing phase and witch for table in it's final shape?

I using postgres\mysql if it matters.

Comment: I don't demand only one of these solutions. You can advise any technique.

Comment: it's called normalisation, and Yes it is a good idea...

Comment: @Mitch Wheat but i lose performance very significantly. Also, there will be too many joins. Something wrong here, I feel it over-engineered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PostgreSQL NULLS cost virtually nothing (1 bit each, 8 bits at a time, plus word alignment, so having > 1 NULL they get cheaper and cheaper versus a value).

For sparsely populated columns like yours, there is NO gain in moving the column to its own table and pretty big loss on joining all the time to get that sparse data.

Answer (score 0):

> So, for example, I have City column. 95% of City values are NULL. Is
>   this good idea to make table like city_names(Id PK, City) and replace
>   City with new column City_id (FK references city_names(id))?

If you replace the city column with a city_id column, 95% of the rows will still be NULL, won't they?  You'll reduce disk space, but you'll require a join for every query that has to return a city name.

Replacing text with ID numbers has nothing to do with normalization. Normalization always reduces the number of columns in the original table.

There's also the problem that "city" by itself usually isn't the full name of a city. You might actually need to move two or three columns into another table.  There are a lot of cities named "Washington" in the USA. In fact, in the 1800s, there were two cities named "Washington, California, USA". For cities in the USA, it might make sense to move city, state, and country together into a new table.  Again, this will reduce disk space, but require a join for every query that has to return any of those columns.

Right now, any query can return all 80 columns of human-readable text using no joins. If you replace, say, half the text columns with foreign key references to id numbers in other tables, you might have to write queries with 40 joins to get all the data back to a point humans can read it again.

Think long and hard before you make changes that require 40 joins.

Having said all that, an 80-column table that's 95% NULL isn't likely to be in BCNF, and normalizing to BCNF or 5NF might help you. Just keep in mind that normalizing doesn't mean "replace that text with an id number".

Comment: "Think long and hard before you make changes that require 40 joins." Yes. This. Thanks for advice. I will read more stories about normalization.